# NEMA connector adapter

Tags: ac, wiring, adapter, conversion

I was thinking about buying a commercial griddle to use in my home to expand my cooking space but I found out that it has a [NEMA 6-15](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector) type plug instead of the typical NEMA 5-15 found in homes.  Since I rent my apartment, rewiring the outlet or similar work is not possible.  However since the 6-15 plug is rated at 240VAC, rather than 120VAC like the 5-15, I did not figure that it would be safe/possible for a simple adapter to be used.

Am I correct in thinking this or is there a workaround that would be safe and functional?

Cheers

Comment: migration candidate for DIY.SE

Comment: It almost certainly will require more current than can be supplied by a 120V outlet, even if you did get a transformer for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be on DYI, but I'll answer here anyway. First, assuming the griddle has no control electronics, just a heating element, connecting it to 120V would run it at 25% of normal wattage (half voltage into same resistance yields half amperage; since P=IE, wattage is one-quarter). I'm assuming this would not be acceptable.

Using a transformer to boost the voltage would likely overload the outlet and home circuit as it wold double the amperage draw at 120V.

There is one way to kludge (IMO) this to work. If your apartment is actually fed with two phases of 120V and you can find available outlets on each phase, you can build an adapter to combine the two out-of-phase hots to produce your 240V circuit. The simplest adapter, just wires, is dangerous as if only one of the 120V plugs is connected, you can have leathal voltage on the other. The safer way is to use relays so that the circuit only connects if both hots are plugged in. Search the web for "Quick 220" for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is exactly what I needed to know.